# Relationships before marriage

Tags: sunni, hanafi, love

I love a girl, i have no bad intentions about her. I just wat to to marry her. There is no lust, not even a slightest bad intention. I have only pure intentions just want to marry her  no sexual thing, no, no touching, nothing bad. I just want to know if it is wrong or what is right way?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with it.
You ask her whether she would marry you.
If she wants, you go to her father/wali and arrange the marriage.

(If she does not want, you will have to leave her. There's no marriage allowed against the will of both.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell this person how you feel and go to her dad and ask for her hand in marriage. BUT please do not rush into marriage it might be lust not love. Get to know her for at least a year and also pray ISHTIKARA.